# PyCuda - use *.cubin - named symbol not found

Tags: nvcc, pycuda

I try to use a compiled *.cubin file with PyCuda but I get this error:

```
func = mod.get_function("doublify")
pycuda._driver.LogicError: cuModuleGetFunction failed: named symbol not found
```

Content of doublify.cu:

```c
    __global__ void doublify(float *a)
    {
        int idx = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y * 4;
        a[idx] *= 2;
    }
```

I compiled it with the following command:

```
nvcc --cubin -arch sm_75 doublify.cu
```

This is my python script:

```python
    import pycuda.driver as cuda
    import pycuda.autoinit
    from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
    import numpy

    a = numpy.random.randn(4, 4)
    a = a.astype(numpy.float32)
    a_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(a.nbytes)

    mod = pycuda.driver.module_from_file("doublify.cubin")

    func = mod.get_function("doublify")
    func(a_gpu, block=(4,4,1))

    cuda.memcpy_dtoh(a_doubled, a_gpu)

    print(a)
```

Do I need to pass in additional flags to the nvcc compiler? If I use it with the SourceModule from Pycuda everything is working as expected. It's also not working with compiling a *.fatbin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure it out myself after debugging PyCuda itself. If anyone else stumbles upon the same problem, this is the solution:
I was missing the ***extern "C***" statement at the beginning of the *.cu file.

```c
extern "C"
__global__ void doublify(float *a)
{
        int idx = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y * 4;
        a[idx] *= 2;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Helped me too but the `extern "C"` needs to be placed at the function that is called from pycuda, not just randomly at the beginning of the kernel code. Pycuda solves this automatically when using `SourceModule` function. I had to disable the automatic handling (`no_extern_c=True` parameter) due to includes which otherwise caused `error: this declaration may not have extern "C" linkage`.